# Direct method from Stored Procedure command text to DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

```
 private void Data_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CommonClass_RunProcesses Commoncls = new CommonClass_RunProcesses();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = Commoncls.ExecuteSQL("SELECT Sales = SUM(Sales) from Sales_1 ", 17);
            if (ds != null)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    grdData_Load.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    grdData_Load.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    grdData_Load.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);

                }
```

How can give StoredProc instead of SQL COMMAND all the time.
I need to give SP name usp_SalesofEST
????

Comment: That depends on what `Commoncls` does. Can it be configured to run an SP? If not - you have to resort to standard ADO.NET classes.

Comment: Also does usp_SalesofEST accept any parameters? If so, what are they?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter:No it doesnt accepts any parameters

Comment: @YuriyGalanter:The ouput of SP is 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ds = Commoncls.ExecuteSQL("EXEC usp_SalesofEST", 17);
```

This is the fastest change without knowing what other things your `CommonClass_RunProcesses` class can do. If it has special built-in method for running SPs, you should check them out.